# Merkle-Damgård construction

Tags: collision-resistance, birthday-attack

Let $H^f$ be a hash function designed using Merkle-Damgård construction on $f:\{0,1\}^{2n}\to\{0,1\}^n$. Write an algorithm that makes approximately $2.2^{n/2}$ many queries to $f$ and find four messages that all hash to same value under $H^f$.

I get an idea to use length extension and 2 birthday attack to get four collision. But I am not able to write the appropriate solution.
Can anyone help me to figure out.

Comment: I suggest you (A) write down the definition you get of the hash function for the largest input that requires two evaluations of $f$; (B) explain how you find an internal collision by varying the message input of the first $f$; (C) explain how you find a collision by varying the message input of the second $f$; (D) conclude. I don't get how we obtain $2.2^{n/2}$, I think the expected number of evaluations of $f$ is like $2^{n/2+1.326}$ (which is less for large $n$).

Comment: yes this is approx value @fgrieu

Comment: Perhaps instead of $2.2^{n/2}$, what was meant was $2 \cdot 2^{n/2} = 2 \times 2^{n/2}$

Comment: [cross-posted at CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/141917/94479)